# Passing unescaped equals sign to GNU parallel in args

Tags: bash, escaping, gnu-parallel, quoting

I invoked GNU parallel (on OS X Yosemite, installed using MacPorts, shell is bash 3.2.57) like this:

```
parallel mycommand -o A=5 -o ::: Y=1 Y=2
```

with the intent that it would run the following commands, in parallel:

```
mycommand -o A=5 -o Y=1
mycommand -o A=5 -o Y=2
```

But it actually runs this:

```
mycommand -o A=5 -o Y\=1
mycommand -o A=5 -o Y\=2
```

The backslash causes `mycommand` not to recognize that argument. This is a problem. And even after scanning the man page and reading the [section of the tutorial on quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Quoting), I can't figure out any way to get `parallel` to run the commands without the backslash getting in there. I've tried putting the `Y=` options in a file, I've tried single and double quotes with various levels of nesting, but the output of `parallel --dry-run` always shows `Y\=`. Is there some way I can get the backslash out?

Comment: If you are using bash it will normally de-quote the \=.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
parallel eval mycommand -o A=5 -o ::: Y=1 Y=2
```